# Can I set up Wi-Fi and USB tethering on the Galaxy Nexus without rooting it?

Tags: wifi-tethering, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-tethering, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I am about to buy the Samsung Galaxy Nexus and I need to tether with the following connections

1. USB to my Windows PC
2. Wi-Fi with my Mac, iPad or iPhone (to download apps over 20MB)

I will be using Verizon Wireless's LTE 4G connection to my smartphone

I also don't want to root my phone, install a custom rom or pay Verizon $20/GB

I heard of PDANet and EasyTether and Tether.com but they only provide USB connectivity to the Mac or PC (I won't be able to use it with iPhone's or iPads)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am willing to pay for the software if it provides Wi-Fi and USB. (Bluetooth is optional but not needed)

Comment: I would assume that just like with previous devices if you want wifi tethering you're going to have to root it (unless Verizon did not disable it).

Comment: Is it hard to root a "Pure" google phone?

Comment: No, it's pretty straightforward since the bootloader is unlockable, and much easier than other devices. Koushik Dutta has instructions up [on his Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/1Jsh9xPwnQP).

Comment: Is verizon so bad? I can do all this without rooting or applications in Belgium: http://cl.ly/1V0h2x1s2r2M1p35230z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClockworkMod Tether](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/1Yy1jb9z4TA#103583939320326217147/posts/1Yy1jb9z4TA) does USB tethering without root and Bluetooth tethering is planned (it's still in alpha).  Unfortunately, from what I understand only Windows, Linux & Mac OS will be supported, but who knows what will happen in the future (maybe Wi-Fi support).  Koush's apps are great.

Answer (score 1):

I use PDAnet for the USB tether (which is something like $16) and FoxFi (Free on the Android Market)  FoxFi enables Wi-Fi WITHOUT rooting.  I use it all the time, even for running my kids Wii.  Should work fine for running your tablets, iPhones, and iPads, etc.  Works great for using my laptop while traveling also.

They both work awesome for me.