# How can I get wired tethering on the Galaxy Rush to a WinXP?

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I have a Samsung Galaxy rush that I would like to tether. I assume that it does not support wireless tethering, but it should do wired. Will I need to root the device? How would I do that?

Comment: @Izzy: I think that's the opposite direction; it sounds like the OP wants normal (phone => PC) USB tethering. Ian: Does your phone have settings for either of these built in? Both are supported since Android 2.2 (IIRC) but carriers sometimes disable/block them. Check `Settings -> Wireless & Networks` for any tethering options. On ICS or later it should be `Settings -> More...` under the wireless group at the top.

Comment: Oh -- yes, you're probably right with that. So make it [How do I enable USB tethering on a JellyBean device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28536/16575), [Can I set up Wi-Fi and USB tethering on the Galaxy Nexus without rooting it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17049/16575), or [How can I share the internet connection of my HTC Wildfire ( Android 2.2 ) via Bluetooth or USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14356/16575) ...

Comment: @eldarerathis: It does not have settings for it as far as I can tell.